# Click on a button and display new html element

Tags: html, angularjs

```
     <div>
        ToDo<br>
        <input ng-show="add" type="checkbox" >{{val}}
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ToDo">
        <input type="button" ng-click="addToDo()" name="btn" placeholder="add todo here" ng-model="add" value="add" />
    </div>
```

And the javascript:

```
  var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
        app.controller("myctrl",function($scope,$log){
            $scope.addToDo = function(){
                $scope.val = $scope.ToDo;
            }
        });
```

If i click on the 'add' button, a checkbox should appear along with the text of the texxtbox. But only text is showing, no checkbox. How do i display the checkbox?

Comment: What does `addToDo()` do?  What is the resulting markup?

Comment: Please, add more code, we can't see your addToDo()

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post the script. Please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have  to call the function in your controller and update some variable to true/ false. Based on the value and using ng-if directive, you can toggle the HTML element.

```js
$scope.displayCheckBox = false;
$scope.val = "someRandoValue";

$scope.addToDo = function() {
  $scope.displayCheckBox = true;
};
```

```html
<div>
  ToDo<br>
  <span ng-if="displayCheckBox">
    <input type="checkbox" >{{val}}
  </span>
</div>
```